# Flexible app engine version custom service account via terraform

Tags: google-app-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I am able to create a flexi app engine version with custom service account. So basically in app.yaml file if I pass something like this

runtime: custom

env: flex

service: test

service_account: "somecustomserviceaccount"

I am able to create the app engine service version and it works fine. I need to automate and do the same via terraform but in the documentation of terraform resource "google_app_engine_flexible_app_version" I could not find a similar agrument.

Please let me know if this is feasible and if not what is the alternate to do it via terraform

Comment: Hi, you can take a look to : https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-on-gcp-with-terraform